# Mac OSX 10.10 Yosemite - Rake aborted! LoadError: cannot load such file -- iconv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, load, rake

It seems that my ruby version auto updated to 2.0.0 after I upgraded my OSX to Yosemite.

It failed me when I tried to do

```
rake db:migrate
```

My application supports version 1.9.3 and I am uncertain that is the cause of such error.

```
$ rake db:migrate --trace
rake aborted! LoadError: cannot load such file -- iconv
/Users/jinqyu/Documents/Chocolicious/config/application.rb:5:in `require'
/Users/jinqyu/Documents/Chocolicious/config/application.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/jinqyu/Documents/Chocolicious/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:687:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/usr/bin/rake:37:in `<main>'
```

I found few links installing ruby 1.9.3 but I don't know which one to use. 
I followed a guide from http://www.curvve.com/blog/guides/2013/install-ruby-1-9-3-mac-osx-10-8-macports-rvm/

However, I can't even run the first command

```
$sudo port selfupdate -v
```

after installing macPort. It says command not found.

Any ror warriors has the same problem as me and had solved it? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Downgraded ruby version to 1.9.3 and the app works fine! HOORAY!
So apparently the version is the cause of such error.

Here's the steps I took to resolve the error, open your terminal.

1. Install RVM with a Ruby, copy & paste:

   ```
   $ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
   $ rvm get head
   ```
2. Install Ruby

   ```
   $ rvm use --install 1.9.3
   ```
3. Bundle install & rake:db

   ```
   $ bundle install
   $ rake db:migrate
   ```

Tell me if it solves your problem. I might missed out some steps after trying many other solutions that I found online. 
p/s: you might have to install homebrew beforehand. cheers! :)

source: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/3099

Comment: Glad this worked, but I would have prefered a solution that worked with Ruby 2.0

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve it, please add the following gem in the gem file, it would help you from being downgraded.

**gem "iconv", "~> 1.0.3"**